# Stepper motor code - GPIO.LOW not needed?

Tags: gpio, python, hardware

I am following the Freenove code (ref:- FNK0020 page 202 https://www.freenove.com/tutorial.html) to program a stepper motor. I have simplified the code a little, in any case as far as I can tell the final GPIO.LOW seems completely redundant, am I missing something?

```
motor_pins = (1, 2, 3, 4)
step = (0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08)

for j in range(0, 4):
    for i in range(0, 4):
        GPIO.output(motor_pins[i], ((step[j] == 1<<i) and GPIO.HIGH or GPIO.LOW))
```

so the code is cycling through each pin, for each step cycle, and the output is `condition and HIGH or LOW`. For each cycle through the step, one  of the pins returns `HIGH` and the rest `LOW` but I can't understand why the `or LOW` is needed at the end because the `AND` function will only return a `True` condition for one of the pins while the rest will be `False` therefore I think the `or LOW` is redundant, can someone clarify?

Comment: it does not take much to run a test to determine if GPIO.LOW is redundant .... don't fall into a trap of thinking that if you do not set an output to HIGH, then it is magically set to LOW

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple programming Question, not specific to the Pi.

It appears to be the python equivalent of the `?=` conditional expression

There appears to be nothing unusual, although *clever programming* tricks like this just make code like this difficult to maintain.
It would be clearer if the author used parentheses.

NOTE In this particular case it is not strictly necessary (as GPIO.LOW == 0 == False and would be converted by the interpreter) but in general the extra term is needed.

Incidentally, if you replaced the `GPIO.output` with `print` the operation would be obvious. Understanding why takes a more in depth understanding of python expression evaluation.